# Pipe operator in R4.1

Tags: r, pipe

The pipe operator in R4.1 has changed to |>. Rstudio signals warning, whose message is unrecognised token ">". The command is executed but the object is not correctly displayed.
I am using tidyverse and purrr packages in rstudio1.4.1103. There was no problem with pipe operator %>% with R0.5. The problem arose in updating to R4.1. Now the program does not run with %>%. If it changed to |> the program runs but Rstudio signals warning. There is a bug somewhere. I need help in figuring it out.